# Java Script / jQuery, how to go do different pages and trigger clicks at different interval times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 pages with 3 buttons:

index1.php `<input type="submit" value="button1" id="submit_btn"/>`

index2.php `<input type="submit" value="button2" id="submit_btn"/>`

index3.php `<input type="submit" value="button3" id="submit_btn"/>`

what i want is to create a script that goes to `index1` and clicks on the `button1` then waits 10 min and goes to `index2.php` and clicks to `button2`.

i could use `$('#button1').click();` and the `setTimeout(function(){..}` function, but how do i handle errors like if the page is not loaded, or if there is a server error and the page needs to be refreshed...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a master page hosted at the same domain, which loads the other pages in an iframe and uses `contentWindow` to access the document inside and press the button. If the page in the iframe fails to load, the master page could detect this and reload the iframe automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setTimeout` from each page as it is loaded. There is no way to call setTimeout in one page and make it activate a script on another page.

Also, there is no way to catch server errors in a page load. The script is part of the page, so if the page is not loaded, there is no script to catch that problem.

That is, unless you're using AJAX, but if I understand correctly, you don't, right?

Comment: yeah, i don't use ajax, yet :), i have to find a way. maybe i could use php